# SAGA command line not working

Tags: saga, reclassify, rqgis

I'm trying to script a reclassification using SAGA `Grid_Tools-Reclassify Grid Values` tool but I'm having the error: `Reclassify Grid Values: could not initialize data objects`.

I've tried different things:

1. With the SAGA GUI: works but I need to script it so it is not practical
2. With rqgis: Doesn't give me an error, but doesn't produce any files
3. With RSAGA: Gives me the `could not initialize data objects`error
4. Directly in the Windows system console: Gives me the `could not initialize data objects`error again.

I'll focus my question on the last try as it's a more direct connection to SAGA.  BTW, I'm using SAGA 2.3.2 64 bits on windows Server 2012 R2.

My system call is:

`"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\saga\saga_cmd.exe" -f=q grid_tools 15 -INPUT "C:\temp\depth_D500.tif" -METHOD "2" -RESULT "C:\temp\bldg_vuln_curves_SAGA_D500.tif" -RETAB "C:\temp\bldg_vuln_curves_SAGA.csv" -TOPERATOR "0"`

And the result:

```
_____________________________________________

   #####   ##   #####    ##
  ###     ###  ##       ###
   ###   # ## ##  #### # ##
    ### ##### ##    # #####
 ##### #   ##  ##### #   ##
_____________________________________________

_____________________________________________
library path:   C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\saga\modules\grid_tools.dll
library name:   Grid - Tools
tool name   :   Reclassify Grid Values
author      :   Copyrights (c) 2005 by Volker Wichmann
_____________________________________________

Load table: C:\temp\bldg_vuln_curves_SAGA.csv...
okay


Parameters


Grids: No objects
Files: C:\temp\depth_D500.tif
Transformation: yes
Interpolation: B-Spline Interpolation


loading: C:\temp\depth_D500.tif



Driver: GTiff

Bands: 1

Rows: 3600

Columns: 3600



Transformation:

  x' = -89.000000 + x * 0.000278 + y * 0.000000

  y' = 55.000000 + x * 0.000000 + y * -0.000278


loading band [1/1]
Reclassify Grid Values: could not initialize data objects
Error: executing tool [Reclassify Grid Values]
```

It seems like SAGA can read the input raster and the classification table without any problems, but he can't write the files or something.  I suspected an administrative right issue but I have all the rights on that folder.  I also have plenty of storage place so that's not the problem either.  I've already had problem with SAGA writing tif files, so I've also tried changing the RESULT files to `.sgrd` and `.sdat` with no luck.

My files can be downloaded here:

[raster](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zsmz5kxp0d86tu/depth_D500.tif?dl=0)

[table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7tpbiezchgltlt0/bldg_vuln_curves_SAGA.csv?dl=0)

Any idea what the problem is?

Note: I've had better luck making the grass `r.reclass` tool work, however it doesn't handle well the floating values so it's not an option.

Comment: Try to load the Tool thru the Gui, then "Save to Script File. Most of the parameters have an "=" between param name and value. Your command line parameters do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally fixed it.  I think there where multiple problems which made more complicated finding a solution.

First error, SAGA command requires a `.sgrd` file.  You CANNOT give it a `.tif`.  This happens only if you script SAGA, has using tif file in the GUI works fine.  I had that problem before and I had tried this solution here, but it didn't help probably because I had another problem.

The other problem is more obscure.  I didn't find it exactly but I think the `-f=q` is causing problems sometimes.  If it's there you need the `=` sign, if it's not there you don't (thanks to @klewis to help me figure it out).  Very weird...  Anyway, here is the command that works

```
"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\saga\saga_cmd.exe" grid_tools 15 -INPUT C:\Users\Bastien\Pictures\depth_D500.sgrd -RESULT C:\Users\Bastien\Pictures\depth_D500SAGA.sgrd -METHOD "2" -RETAB C:\temp\bldg_vuln_curves_SAGA.csv -TOPERATOR 0
```